# Web programming totally in Java or based on Symfony

Tags: java, symfony, web

Recently I've started working in a computer engineering group, our goal is to make a new social networking for students.

Few days ago a telecommunication engineer joined us and he has convinced our boss (who doesn't have any knowledge of computing) to make the whole project in Java, when we had already discussed and decided to use an architecture based on Symfony.

We would like to hear all the possible opinions to convince the boss that his decision is wrong (or for us to realize that we were wrong).

(Our project is not a small one, we are thinking in using a good server, having a big database. This is why this decision is very important to us).

Thanks beforehand and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: symfony and PHP fans will try to convince you that Symfony is the best invention since sliced bread. Java fans will try to convince you that PHP is a language for script kiddies and that Java is the only viable solution. In the end, it boils down to the tastes and competences of the team.

Comment: Ignorant people will always claim there's a universal tool that should be used for everything, and it's usually the tool they're the most familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the fact to do a project in full Java is a bad decision.

The problem here is that you choose Symfony as a team, because you know you are more comfortable with PHP, you are event probably excited about it. And some guy, out of nowhere, just want to do something else, egoistically.

I invite you to read this little story:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicken_and_the_Pig

And instead of focusing your argument on proving Symfony is nice, try to push organisation arguments. Saying that a team that can make their own decisions is better, etc... (Talking about Agile maybe)?

My point is: The problem is not the technology. Therefore, I don't think you can win with technological argument. If this guy speak louder, the boss will listen.

Comment: As you suggested I read the story, really interesting. The other day we had a meeting and thanks to the arguments I gave we arrive to an understanding. Your solution was vey useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Symfony explained to my Boss](http://symfony.com/explained-to-my-boss).

Additionally you should familiarize with explanation for different team members [What is Symfony](http://symfony.com/what-is-symfony) section *ELEVATOR PITCHES*.